# get the index of the div using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="hp_class">
        This is div1.
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="newsletter" name="myForm" method="post">    
            <div class="hp_rt">
                <div class="subscribe subs_failure">Subscribe now</div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="hp_class">
        This is div3.
    </div>
</div>
```

> I need the index of the `div` tag,
>
> For example, if I click on `Subscribe now`, i need the index of it as 2
>
> the code i tried is

```
$('.hp_rt>.subscribe').click(function(){
    var div_count=$(this).parent('.hp_promo_rt').parents('div').index($(this).parent('.hp_rt').parents('div'));
    alert(div_count);
});
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: how 2? i dont think Div index will be 2 ...

Comment: u need how many divs?

Comment: Need to be absolutely jquery or is it possible to use another way? Because is on much better and easier.

Comment: it could've been in javascript too, but thanks...I've got the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
$('.hp_rt>.subscribe').click(function() {
    var $div = $(this).parents('.top > div'); // This is the Div you want the index of!
    var $prevs = $div.prevAll('div'); // This are all the Divs before the Div!
    var number = $prevs.size() + 1; // There is one div before the div in question, so this gives 2 in this case.
});
```

Alternatively you could use index():

```
$('.hp_rt>.subscribe').click(function() {
    var $div = $(this).parents('.top > div'); // This is the Div you want the index of!
    var number = $div.index() + 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks yaar....The first one worked out for me
much similar `$(this).closest('form').parent().prevAll('div').size();`

Comment: @DebjeetDas your solution is not modular at all, what if sometime in the future you need to change your structure and wrap your form in another element, it would break your code

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.subscribe').click(function(){
    var i = $(this).closest('form').parent().index();
    console.log(i);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dGRYJ/).

Although JavaScript is zero-based, so this will return (given your posted HTML) `1`, not `2`.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score 1):

So I understand you want the index in relation to the direct children of `.top`, the use this

```
$('.hp_rt>.subscribe').click(function(){
   alert($(this).closest('.top > div').index());
});
```

This will give you a zero-based index, you can add 1 to get the alert as "2"